# Group data by year/month/day in prometheus

Tags: prometheus

As the title says, I am looking for a way to get the maximum value of a time series, which resets daily. After this task is achieved I would like to create a sum over those values to get a value per month/year. What is the best way to achieve this in Prometheus?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As described in my post on [prometheus-developers](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/prometheus-developers/pul4HF4OS0E/tYiPP_paBgAJ), here is a possible option, although it's far from readable:

```
up{job="prometheus"} + ignoring(year, month, day) group_right
  count_values without() ("year", year(timestamp(
    count_values without() ("month", month(timestamp(
      count_values without() ("day", day_of_month(timestamp(
        up{job="prometheus"}
      )))
    )))
  ))) * 0
```

Replace both instances of `up{job="prometheus"}` with whatever series selector you need. No idea how efficient this is, though. :o)

Comment: Could you explain what is the idea behind this? Thanks for the solution anyway

Comment: The whole point of the `count_values_without(...)` block is to get a time series with the same labels plus `year`, `month` and `day`as the original time series (and a garbage value). Then you do `+ ignoring(year, month, day) group_right <timeseries_with_year_month_day> * 0` in order to attach the `year`, `month` and `day` labels to the original time series' value.

Now that this new time series has labels that identify each day, you can aggregate by day whichever way you want by filtering by those labels.

Comment: if we assume `up{job="prometheus"}` is a counter...would I just wrap the above around `sum(increase( what-you-have-above ))` to graph it? when I do that...I get an error `Error executing query: invalid parameter 'query': 2:3: parse error: expected type range vector in call to function "increase", got instant vector`

Comment: I should have said "replace both instances of `up{job="prometheus"}` with whatever *expression* you need aggregated by date`. So you'd need `sum(increase(your_counter[5m]))` to appear twice in the query above (replacing `up{job="prometheus"}`).

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to add to the excellent answer by Alin Sînpălean. He splits the data into time series per day. You can [similarly](https://sysrant.com/posts/monthly-reports-with-grafana-and-prometheus/) split them per month and then use the Grafana reduce "series to rows" transform to calculate the total per month. You need another sort transform to get the rows back in order. This only works well when you add a leading zero to the month number. Then you can use "{{year}}-{{zero}}{{month}}" as your legend which sorts correctly.

```
label_replace(
  up{job="prometheus"} + ignoring(year, month) group_right
    count_values without() ("year", year(timestamp(
      count_values without() ("month", month(timestamp(
        up{job="prometheus"}
      )))
    ))) * 0,
  "zero",
  "0",
  "month",
  "^[0-9]$"
)
```