# PromQL filter based on current date

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a metric that looks like this:

```
my_metric{index_name="cool_index_2021-10-03"} 1
```

And of course the date changes every day.
I want to dynamically query this metric for today only, using the label `index_name`.

Is it possible to do something like this? (of course this is not working):

```
my_metric{index_name="cool_index_" + year() + "-" + month() + "-" + day()}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You could use a separate programming language to construct the queries and call the [query API](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/api/#instant-queries). Or, drop the `index_name` filter and use the query from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52183866/13487034) to group by day.